# Use a URL template in jsp:include or c:import in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, rest, spring-mvc

I would like to use a URL generated with spring's `<spring:url>` in a `<jsp:include>` tag, but   it is appending the context path twice. I am using Spring MVC 3.1.

```
<spring:url var="publicationUrl" value="/publications/{id}">
   <spring:param name="id" value="${publication.id}" />
</spring:url>

<!-- publicationUrl = "/myApp/publications/1234" -->

<!-- Both methods fail because they are appending the -->
<!-- context again: "/myApp/myApp/publications/1234"  -->
<jsp:include page="${publicationUrl}" />    
<c:import url="${publicationUrl}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to prevent `spring:url` from prepending the context path. I have to add an empty context:

```
<spring:url var="publicationUrl" value="/publications/{id}" context="">
   <spring:param name="id" value="${publication.id}" />
</spring:url>
```

This solution is not perfect as I have to create two different URLs: one for the links and another one for the includes.